# Pass complex type with typeparam to child RenderFragment as CascadeParameter

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor component "Table" with a `RenderFragment` parameter "TableHeader", containing a collection of `TableHeaderColumn` elements. This is an example usage of the Table component:

```
<Table Items="@Persons">
    <TableHeader>
        <TableHeaderColumn Label="First Name" />
        <TableHeaderColumn Label="Last Name" />
    </TableHeader>
    <TableRow>
    ......
    </TableRow>
</Table>
```

Using `CascadingValue`, I want to pass the Table instance to all `TableHeaderColumn` instances in the "TableHeader" render fragment, but I cannot get this to work for some reason.

My theory is that this is not possible as long as Table component is using a `TItem typeparam`, while `TableHeaderColumn` component is not.

This is the Table.razor file:

```
@typeparam TItem
@inherits TableBase<TItem>

<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <CascadingValue Value="this">
            @TableHeader
         </CascadingValue>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   ....
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

TableBase.cs:

```
public class TableBase<TItem>
{
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment TableHeader { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment<TItem> TableRow { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class TableHeaderColumnBase
{
    [CascadingParameter]
    public Table<object> Table { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, since the `TableHeaderColumn` component is not using a `typeparam`, I am using "object" as Table type. Not sure if this is the right approach.

The cascading parameter in `TableHeaderColumnBase` does not get populated and I am not sure how I can get this to work.

If I pass one of the properties on the Table-instance instead, like "this.Title", it works fine.

Anyone knows what I am missing or if this is even possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the TItem element to the TableHeaderColumnBase component

```
<Table Items="@Persons">
<TableHeader>
    <TableHeaderColumn TItem="Person" Label="First Name" />
    <TableHeaderColumn TItem="Person" Label="Last Name" />
</TableHeader>
<TableRow>
......
</TableRow>
```

In the TableHeaderColumn.razor file, add a parameter

```
 [CascadingParameter] public Table<TItem> ParentTable { get; set; }
```

and `@typeparam TItem` at the top.

You can now call all the methods and access the variables of the parent component and use the TItem as you whish.